# Android custom ProgressBar is distorted or doubled

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I just stumbled into a problem with creating custom progress bar that i do not understand. I use the common method to create the animation-list then apply it to the progressbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:oneshot="false">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dw_pb_1"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dw_pb_2"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dw_pb_3"
        android:duration="100"/>

</animation-list>
```

And I apply it to a progressbar:

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="150"
            android:layout_height="150"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/dw_loader" />
```

But the result is the following:

[image]

It draws the drawable again next to the original progressbar. If I use wrap_content to width and height of the progressbar this is what i get:
[image]

****SOLUTION?**: I cannot imagine why but if I set the drawable programmatically it works...**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make your own custom progress bar. In your res/drawable, create an XML file, name it loading_indertiminate.xml for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_spinner"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

And, in your layout, just make this for your Progess bar.

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_indertiminate" />
```

Comment: I need a frame by frame custom progress bar. You just gave me another kind of animation which might have the same effect. The issue has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sorry in this case you may need to use the ViewAnimator.

Comment: http://gaudicos.blogspot.hu/2013/10/customized-progress-bar.html Check the last progressbar, i do not need to use ViewAnimator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is `ProgressBar` will try to replicate its drawable it has more space. Respectively crops if there is not enough room.

You can solve this problem with scaling the items:

```
<item android:duration="100">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/@drawable/dw_pb_1"
            android:scaleGravity="center" />
</item>
```

With repeating for each item.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you a little by giving a custom progressdialog class which worked for me.

MyProgressDialog.class

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message) {
    return show(context, title, message, false);
}

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
}

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
}

public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    /* The next line will add the ProgressBar to the dialog. */
    dialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar(context), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dialog.show();

    return dialog;
}

public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
}
```

And use it like:

```
MyProgressDialog mProgress = MyProgressDialog.show(context, title, message);
```

Dismiss like the same: `mProgress.dismiss();`

If you want the transparent background with the only progress just do like:

```
 MyProgressDialog mProgress = MyProgressDialog.show(context, null, null);
```

Use it..

Comment: Sorry; This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @OrhanC1 Thanks for a good comment. But I tried here to help by an other approah. may be some other can use it.

Comment: @RanjitPati - Help who? The problem isn't your approach, it's that the answer doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue no longer occurs since the Android version 6.0 (Marshmallow API Level 23).
For prior versions support, the solution provided by @wrecker still working.